# Empty line in foreach loop

Tags: php

Starting off I have looked at other answers and tried them but none resolve my issues. I have an empty result in a foreach loop. The code is:

```
<?php 
    $prices = explode(",", $products['price']);
    $quantities = explode(",", $products['quantity']);
    foreach($prices as $key => $val){
       echo $val ." / ". $quantities[$key]."<br>";
    }
?>
```

this give me this response:

$11.00 / 100 foot roll
30.00 / 250 foot roll
46.00 / 500 foot roll
79.00 / 1000 foot roll
/

You can see it at work here: https://abcole.me/monty/?shop&shop_id=117 The site is still under construction, but this is the last bug and I feel once this is fixed, I'll be able to use the same code for the drop downs.

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($prices);` and `var_dump($quantities);` ?

Comment: $array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "9.50" [1]=> string(5) "19.00" [2]=> string(5) "29.00" [3]=> string(5) "52.00" [4]=> string(0) "" } 

array(5) { [0]=> string(13) "100 foot roll" [1]=> string(13) "250 foot roll" [2]=> string(13) "500 foot roll" [3]=> string(14) "1000 foot roll" [4]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: It's because of an extra ',' in the database on all lines. How do I make the query forget that?

Here's a line from the database so you can see what I mean:
100 foot roll,250 foot roll,500 foot roll,1000 foot roll,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try trimming the last ','. Like this:

```
<?php 
    $prices = explode(",", trim($products['price'], ', '));
    $quantities = explode(",", trim($products['quantity'], ', '));
    foreach($prices as $key => $val){
       echo $val ." / ". $quantities[$key]."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much!!